# How to call pushing box api in mcbstr9 arm evaluation board?

Tags: api, get, arm, iot, keil

I am a beginner in working with the *MCBSTR9* arm board.
I am trying to use the *ESP8266* wifi module in TCP mode with the **pushingbox API**.
After connecting to the API, pushingbox is  unable to send a request `GET /pushingbox?devid=deviceid HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: api.pushingbox.com\r\n\r\n`.

My Question is how to include the new line key in keil c. I have used `\r\n` for it but it's not working. It works with ESP 8266 user application, though.

This is the code I tried:

```c
/*ESP8266-01*/
char data[] = "GET /pushingbox?devid=*************&tag=but HTTP/1.0";
char data1[] = "Host: api.pushingbox.com";
char data2[] = "";
void at(void) {
  sendchar1('A');
  sendchar1('T');
  sendchar1('\r');
  sendchar1('\n');
  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    lcd_putchar(getkey1());
}
void atcwmode(void) {
  char ch[] = "AT+CWMODE=3\r\n"
  for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    sendchar1(ch[i]);
  for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    lcd_putchar(getkey1());
    if (i == 14)
      set_cursor(0, 1);
  }
}
void atcipmux(void) {
  char ch[] = "AT+CIPMUX=0\r\n";
  for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    sendchar1(ch[i]);
  for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    lcd_putchar(getkey1());
    if (i == 14)
      set_cursor(0, 1);
  }
}
void atcwjap(void) {
  char ch[] = "AT+CWJAP?\r\n";
  for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    sendchar1(ch[i]);
  for (i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
    lcd_putchar(getkey1());
    if (i == 16)
      set_cursor(0, 1);
  }
}
void atsend() {
  char ch[] = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(ch); i++)
    sendchar1(ch[i]);
  sendchar1('8');
  sendchar1('5');
  sendchar1('\r');
  sendchar1('\n');
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  set_cursor(0, 1);
  lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  wait();
  wait();
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(data) - 1; i++)
    sendchar1(data[i]);
  GPIO7 - > DR[0x3FC] = 0xFF;

  set_cursor(0, 0);
  GPIO7 - > DR[0x3FC] = 0x00;
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  set_cursor(0, 1);
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  set_cursor(0, 0);
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    lcd_putchar(getkey1());
  set_cursor(0, 1);
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    lcd_putchar(getkey1());
}
```

I have tried using the esp user application by sending
    POST /pushingbox?devid=vD12658A9BB09A13&tag=but HTTP/1.0\r\n
    Host: api.pushingbox.com:80

It works and my pushing box scenario gets updated.
But it doesn't work with the board.

Comment: I think it needs KEIL professional version, If anybody has the link to download, share it here